# Django Docker How to only migrate in Container?

Tags: python, django, docker

Question can be little unclear so let me explain. I have a Django Project and for this time I wanted to use Docker. So I dockerized my project from the tutorials on the internet.

*As Django users know, if you want to extend the user model you need to make migrations afterwards you edit the model*

So I was editing my custom user model and wanted to test a feature for my model. What I wanted to achieve was, test migrated version of my Django app on Docker container and if it fits my needs I would make the migration on local files. But after I ran the `docker-compose exec web python manage.py make migrations users` command my also local files changed.

So my question is, if I want to test a feature on migrated version of my app can I test it on Docker container and then migrate on local machine? or did I not understand the logic of docker?

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
            - ./app/:/backend/
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=admin
            - POSTGRES_DB=db
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of Docker as a virtual machine having a ready environment to run your application. Now ask your question.

Comment: Then why the changes happened in my local machine instead of only in virtual env?

Comment: Maybe because you are using a volume in your app root directory? So it's created the migration files there?

Comment: Than how can I not use a volume in my root dir? what is the way for that?

Comment: Volumes are used when you want to persist some files in your container. Make sure volumes are mapped to safe dirs on host.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run migrate each time when you up the docker, you can do it as

Create a file `entrypoint.sh` in the same path where your docker-compose.yml present.

`entrypint.sh` is a bash file that contains the commands to run before running your server, inisde it you can add following code :-

```
python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

Your `docker-compose.yml` will be

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        entrypoint: /code/entrypoint.sh # path where you placed your entrypoint.sh file
        volumes: 
            - ./app/:/backend/
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=admin
            - POSTGRES_DB=db
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

For more information you can take reference from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#entrypoint)